# problem in connecting to oracle 10g express edition through java

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g, database-connection

I'm unable to connect Oracle 10g database.I am getting exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

The code is:

```
try {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:system","user" ,"pass");
    stmt=con.createStatement();
}
```

.......

How can i proceed?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have a space `" "` in your driver class name

Change,

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDrive r");
```

to,

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

Also, fix this error from:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle: thin:@localhost:1521:system","user" ,"pass");
```

to

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:system","user" ,"pass");
```

Comment: still i am getting same exception

Comment: You will have to put your oracle driver jar in your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to replace system with XE in "jdbc:oracle: thin:@localhost:1521:system"

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space between the 'e' and the 'r'?

Answer (score 0):

You have the Oracle driver in your classpath?

Comment: How to set class classpath?                                       E:\Oracle\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar is this jar file I have to put in project library?

Comment: Depends on your IDE.  Do you have a more experienced coworker to ask?

Answer (score 0):

Its a problem with the given url. Please correct the url with accurate host name,port no,user name & password.Do not use the port number(8080) that you are using with browser when you are running you application oracle 10g express edition.Simply user the default port number 1521.

Please find the example below:-

```
String driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";            

Class.forName(driver);
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","manoj","manoj");
```

- user name=manoj
- password=manoj
- port no=1521
- service name=XE
- Host=Localhost